# how to select multiple images with magento form field

Tags: magento-1.9, image, upload, fieldsets

I have the question i am posting is sily and asked many times on this forum but no wer the answer posted by others was solved my issue.

my question is i have fieldset of file and need to upload images with multiple so i had used

```
 $fieldset->addField('optionimage', 'file', array(
        'label'     => $helper->__('Option Image'),
        'required'  => false,
        'name'      => 'optionimage[]',
        'multiple'=>true,
        'multiple'=>'multiple'
  ));
```

but i am failed to add multiple the above field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default you cannot do this.
I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19224363/2047249) why is not possible out of the box and how you can make it work.
The explanation is for image inputs but it works the same for image fields.
The idea is that "multiple" is not an allowed attribute for file inputs.
You need to create your won input renderer that extends `Varien_Data_Form_Element_File` (or `Image` if you need it for images) and make it allow `multiple` as attribute.

so your renderer can look like this

```
<?php 
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_[Entity]_Helper_Image extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Image //or _File if you are not uploading images
{
    //make your renderer allow "multiple" attribute
    public function getHtmlAttributes(){
        return array_merge(parent::getHtmlAttributes(), array('multiple'));
    }
}
```

In your edit form add this:

```
$fieldset->addType('image', '[Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_[Entity]_Helper_Image');
```

or if you don't want to upload only images

```
$fieldset->addType('file', '[Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_[Entity]_Helper_File');
```

and then add your field like this:

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'id_here', 
    'image',  //or file
    array( 
            'name'      => 'image[]', //declare this as array. Otherwise only one image will be uploaded
            'multiple'  => 'multiple', //declare input as 'multiple'
            'label'     => Mage::helper('helper_alias')->__('Image'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('helper_alias')->__('Image'),
            'required'  => true,
        )
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use jquesy to select multiple images

require(['jquery'], function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
console.log('Custom JavaScript is loaded!');
$("#image").prop("multiple", true);
});
});

Comment: I don't think that's what the question is asking. The other answer uses php with no JS anywhere, so the claim that jquery is required is off the mark.